# Send function parameters as arguments to another function js

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

```
function sum(x,y) {return x+y}

function callSum(sum,args){
 return sum(args)
}
```

How to send args so this can work?

Comment: Note: it should be `function` not `Function`.

Comment: You can spread the args after the function so it would be `function callSum(sum, ...args) {return sum(...args)}` This will gather all parameters after `sum` in the outer function into an array, and then spread them back into individual arguments in the inner call. see: [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)